# Uncaught TypeError with jQuery UI's Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am a non-JS programmer trying to use the jQuery UI Datepicker on a web page, which is also using Bootstrap. I followed the instructions for downloading a custom UI library from their site, and set things up as suggested. Right now, I'm loading the following JS files, in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/dp-into-selects.js"></script>
```

(It's version 4.0.0 of Bootstrap; and `jquery-ui.min.js` is what the site generated for me this morning. `dp-into-selects.js` is a short function of my own that processes Datepicker input to and from a group of select boxes.)

When I run this, there's no popup, and the console gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: s.dpDiv[(h || "show")] is not a function
    at i._showDatepicker (jquery-ui.min.js:6)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js:6)
    at HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLImageElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

I've only seen one example of this online, with no solution connected to it. Can anyone offer me a suggestion? I'm assuming that I haven't loaded something I'm supposed to, or there's a version mismatch, but I don't know how to find this out.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself:

Turns out you can't use the jQuery slim build for this; you need AJAX/effects features in order for the Datepicker to work. Switching to the regular jQuery build made everything work fine.